# Tensorflow: save the model with smallest validation error

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I ran a training job with tensorflow and got the following curve for loss on validation set. The net starts to overfit after 6000-th iteration. So I'd like to get the model before overfitting.

[image: loss]

My training code is something like below:

```
train_step = ......
summary = tf.scalar_summary(l1_loss.op.name, l1_loss)
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("checkpoint", sess.graph)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
for i in xrange(20000):
    batch = get_next_batch(batch_size)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: batch.x, y:batch.y})
    if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
        saver.save(sess, "checkpoint/net", global_step = i+1)
        summary_str = sess.run(summary, feed_dict=validation_feed_dict)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i+1)
        summary_writer.flush()
```

After training finishes, there is only five checkpoints saved (19600, 19700, 19800, 19900, 20000). Is there any way to let tensorflow save checkpoint according to the validation error?

P.S. I know that `tf.train.Saver` has a `max_to_keep` argument, which in principal could save all the checkpoints. But that's not I wanted (unless it's the only option). I want the saver keep the checkpoint with the smallest validation loss so far. Is that possible?

Comment: You can also try `tf.estimator.BestExporter`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to calculate the classification accuracy on the validation-set and keep track of the best one seen so far, and only write the checkpoint once an improvement has been found to the validation accuracy.

If the data-set and/or model is large, then you may have to split the validation-set into batches to fit the computation in memory.

This tutorial shows exactly how to do what you want:

https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/04_Save_Restore.ipynb

It is also available as a short video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx8JUJROkh0

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with checkpoints.  In tensorflow 1:

```
# you should import other functions/libs as needed to build the model

from keras.callbacks.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# add checkpoint to save model with lowest val loss
filepath = 'tf1_mnist_cnn.hdf5'
save_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, \
                             save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, \
                             mode='auto', period=1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[save_checkpoint])
```

Tensorflow 2:

```
# import other libs as needed for building model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# add a checkpoint to save the lowest validation loss
filepath = 'tf2_mnist_model.hdf5'

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, \
                             save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, \
                             mode='auto', save_frequency=1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Complete demo files are here: https://github.com/nateGeorge/slurm_gpu_ubuntu/tree/master/demo_files.

Answer (score 0):

In your session.run you'll need to explicitely ask for the loss. Then create a list with your last eval-losses and only if the current eval loss is smaller than i.e. the last two saved losses create the checkpoint.